# Centre of ellipse with inscribed trapezoid?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, quadrilateral

Is there a way to find out the centre coordinates of an ellipse given the corner points of a trapezoid inscribed within it? The height and the lengths of AB and CD are known.
Here is a diagram:

[image]

In this, given the points A,B,C and D, is there a way to gain any information about the **ellipse** outside this trapezoid? I realise that its major and minor axes could vary, but can't the centre be found out?

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, this is a part of a computer vision problem I'm trying to find a solution for.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed ellipse is not fully determined.  You need to specify some additional information, such as a fifth point or the length of the minor axis, to define a unique ellipse.

Comment: In my problem, I can also find out middle points between A-C and B-D which lie on the ellipse, if needed. Basically, I can find out _any_ point that lies on the ellipse given a straight horizontal line which passes through it - but these additional lines need to be kept at a minimum. Will that help?

Comment: Give us one additional point on the ellipse to make a total of five points.  You can also specify that the ellipse is tangent to a given line.

Comment: You may assume that the major axis will be parallel to the horizontal lines. A fifth and sixth point can also be found out by drawing a third line and finding two edge points. I'm curious, though - how will five points make it possible to find a unique ellipse?

Comment: Here is why five points specify an ellipse.  You probably know that three points specify a circle.  But for an ellipse in a given plane you have two additional degrees of freedom -- the eccentricity (or equivalently the ratio of the major axis to the minor axis) and the orientation of the major or minor axis.  Adding two more points, for a total of five instead of three, takes up the two additional degrees of freedom.  Also -- a necessary condition to actually have an ellipse instead of a hyperbola is that the five points should be the vertices of a convex pentagon.

Comment: I also foind that assuming the axes parallel to sides of the trapezoid does not really work at keaat for an isosceles trapezoid, and eduted the first comment accordingly.